# Two apps in one device and the image uploaded from first app will appear in the second app

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to make two iOS apps say A and B. Then what I need to do is to upload 5 images from user's gallery in A app and show those 5 images in app B. I tried this with Document Directory but then I came to know that each app has it's own document directory and any other app does not have access to that document directory. Now I don't know how to do this. Any help?

Sorry forgot to mention that I want it done offline, so I can't use an api in both the apps.

Comment: From 1st app,Upload images to Server and In Second app fetch images from server.

Comment: needs to be done ofline, so can't use service.

Comment: Use a shared folder or iCloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can share some data within groups of app as per new updates in `iOS 8.0` and above.

Just you need to create apps group and share your data among that groups app.

Below are few steps to enable app groups.

**Step1:** Enable App group from `Target Setting -> Capabilities -> App Group`

**Sample Group name :** `groups.companyname` or `groups.appgroupname`

[image]

> Note: Every app which you want in this group must have same group name
>   in this section.

**Step 2:** Get General sharing folder where you can store shared data like images DB.

for that you need to get path of that shared folder as mention below

**Objective-C :**

```
- (NSString *)getSharedGroupFolderPath:(NSString*)aAppGroupName {
    NSURL *aContainerPathURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:aAppGroupName];
    return [aContainerPathURL relativePath];
}
```

**Swift:**

```
static func appGroupContainerURL() -> URL? {
  // 1
  let fileManager = FileManager.default
  guard let groupURL = fileManager
    .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: <APP_GROUP_NAME>) else {
      return nil
  }

  let storagePathUrl = groupURL.appendingPathComponent("File Provider Storage")
  let storagePath = storagePathUrl.path
  // 2
  if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: storagePath) {
    do {
      try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: storagePath,
                                              withIntermediateDirectories: false,
                                              attributes: nil)
    } catch let error {
      print("error creating filepath: \(error)")
      return nil
    }
  }
  // 3
  return storagePathUrl
```

}

By above method you can get Group container folder path now save your data here which you need to share among multiple Apps.

**Step3:**

Store your image of file on container path like below

```
guard let destinationURL = TestFileViewController.fileUrlForDocumentNamed("FileName") else {
            return
        }

        let image = UIImage.init(named: "tests")


        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {

            do {
                try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0)!.write(to: destinationURL)
                print("file saved")
            } catch {
                print("error saving file")
            }
        } else {
            print("file already exists")
        }
```

**Use below supported method for getting file path :**

```
// Returns the file URL for the file to be saved at
    static func fileUrlForDocumentNamed(_ name: String) -> URL? {
        guard let baseURL = appGroupContainerURL() else { return nil }

        let protectedName: String
        if name.isEmpty {
            protectedName = "Untitled"
        } else {
            protectedName = name
        }

        return baseURL.appendingPathComponent(protectedName)
            .appendingPathExtension("your file extension")
    }
```

Hope this will helps you to achieve your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add image to that group container folder and retrieve it in other app

Comment: Sure give me one hour I will update my answer as I need to go for meeting. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I will wait for your reply. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135172/discussion-between-codechanger-and-atpl-mohali).

Answer (score 0):

You can use group app. **Project Navigator -> Capabilities -> Turn on group apps.** The groups name entailments must be same name and also need to enable in your developer account. Now you create a directory to shared space then you will access the data or image from both. [image]

//use this code for create share directory

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    guard let groupUrl = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "your app group name") else {
        return nil
    }

    var storagePathUrl = groupUrl.appendingPathComponent("FileProviderStorage")
    let storagePath = storagePathUrl.path

    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: storagePath) {
        do {
           try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: storagePath,  withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        } catch _ {
        }
    } else {
        print("File Path: \(storagePath)")
    }
```

Comment: do I need to add group.(my app group name) in guard let groupUrl = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "your app group name") else {
        return nil

Comment: Thank you. It's working. I have successfully created a shared path